# Error converting data type int to tinyint

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am new to  stored procedures. When i run this i get an error saying Error converting data type int to tinyint. In my C# was the following code:

```
mySqlcmd.CommandText = "EXECUTE PhoneNumber_Insert  @p_PhoneNumberTypeID, @p_PersonID";
mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = 1;
mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "754381";
mysqlConnection.Open();
mySqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
mysqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Cast the `1` to a `byte` (`mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (byte) 1;`). Let me know if it works and I'll write it up as an answer

Comment: post your stored proc. definition. You might have your param types the wrong way around....

Comment: @Flydog57 - i did that and i get this error now.

Comment: "PhoneNumber_Insert expects parameter @PhoneNumberTypeId which was not supplied" 
 mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value= (byte)1;

Comment: `mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "754381";` Why are you passing this as a string?

Comment: Your code is too strange... In MySQL the stored procedure is executed using the keyword `CALL`. Keyword `EXECUTE` is used for to execute prepared statement, for which the keyword `USING` before its parameters is compulsory. And you use user-defined variables as parameters which' values cannot be assigned via `Parameters.Add`.

Comment: about your error, mayby you need to use an `explicitly conversion` mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (byte)1;  or  mySqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering [bug 101302](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101302) in MySQL Connector/NET. There are three possible workarounds:

1. Change your code to explicitly use `MySqlDbType.Byte`: `mySqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@p_PhoneNumberTypeID", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = 1;`
2. Downgrade to MySql.Data 8.0.21.
3. Switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which supports the same API as MySql.Data but is [less buggy](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).

Comment: @MitchWheat It's a problem that happens with various data types; see the duplicated bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101424. That bug report just provided reproduction steps for `BOOL`.